# How do I send additional form data in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Is there another way of sending form data that I could use with the script I'm using, I have tried appending form data but I can't figure out how to get the paired values in the post data, so I added the data within the URL, problem with this is the progress bar and data then stops working on my page.

```
<script>
function _(el){
    return document.getElementById(el);
}
function uploadFile(){
    var file = _("video").files[0];
    var vidName = $("#vidName").val();
    var videoDescription = $("#videoDescription").val();
    var albumName1 = $("#choosevidCat").val();
    var vidFile =$("#video").val();
    var otherData = $('vidUpload').serializeArray()
//       alert(file.name+" | "+file.size+" | "+file.type);
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("video", file);
//  formdata.append("video", vidName);
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
    ajax.open("POST", "includes/vid_upload.inc.php?vidName=" +vidName+"&videoDescription=" +videoDescription+"&albumName1=" 
    +albumName1, false);
    ajax.send(formdata);
}
function progressHandler(event){
    _("loaded_n_total").innerHTML = "Uploaded "+event.loaded+" bytes of "+event.total;
    var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
    _("progressBar").value = Math.round(percent);
    _("status").innerHTML = Math.round(percent)+"% uploaded... please wait";
}
function completeHandler(event){
    _("status").innerHTML = event.target.responseText;
    _("progressBar").value = 0;
}
function errorHandler(event){
    _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Failed";
}
function abortHandler(event){
    _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Aborted";
}
</script>
```

I tried adding

```
formdata.append("video", vidName);
```

as you can see I have commented it out on in the script as webconsole showed although it was sending the vidName variable it didnt have an identifying tag like this: Content-Disposition: form-data; name="video"

testing ogg creation 2

Could anyone help please

Comment: what do you get if you `console.log(FormData.getAll)`

Comment: @Said Kholov Im not sure I added it in the right place, I put in before the closing script tag, it reported back as undefined and that related to that bit of code

Comment: Put it right after append and try to upload

Comment: exactly the same undefined specified to that specific code

Comment: formdata not FormData sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ajax.send("video=" + vidName + "&other=" + other_value);
```

if want to send many values
you can use the keyword "&" to separate name and value pare

like 
video=vidName,
other=othervalue1,
other2=otherevalue2

to send it to the post request do

```
"video=vidname&other=othervalue1&other2=othervalue2"
```

and in PHP you can get those post data

```
$_POST['video'];
$_POST['other'];
$_POST['other2'];
```

Here is a link
[Sending POST data with a XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/sending-post-data-with-a-xmlhttprequest)

Comment: I just tried that but it stops the file im uploading from attatching to the upload function

Comment: @ Oli Soproni B. 5 mins ago The _ is defining use of the first function in the script, it saves having to repeatably type the "$" charachter and no it doesnt create an error

Comment: I have solved it, by using the ajax.open as I was, adding the form data much the way you said in the ajax.send but removing the false has now allowed me to send the data and have my progress bar work

Comment: if found my answer helpful then can accept it as an answer